# how to force horizontal scrolling only on UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with `contentSize` property set to a very large value `1000`, the width of the `UITextView` is 200, scrolling is enabled, horizontal bouncing is enabled and vertical bouncing is disabled but this `UITextView` still scrolls vertically on large text.
how can I force horizontal scrolling on it ?

p.s. [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826980/how-to-enforce-horizontal-scrolling-on-uitextview) does't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried many different ways to have a horizontal scrolling functionality to work as expected, but non of these methods worked for me, so I created a UIScrollView and added a UILabel as a subview in the scroll view, and setting the frame's width of the label dynamically according to its text and the text font, after that I set the contentSize of the scroll view to be equal to the label's new frame width & height. Using this method you will have a horizontal scrolling text.

Answer (score 5):

UITextView is a subclass of - UIScrollView. So you can use ScrollViewDelegate method for disabling this.

Use -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(id)aScrollView
{
    [aScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake([scrollView contentOffset].x, 0.0)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JAHelia's advice, this worked for me:

```
self.dishNameLabel.text = @"Here is some very longgggg text to test with";
float width = ceil([self.dishNameLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"WorkSans-SemiBold" size:15.0]}].width);
self.dishNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.dishNameLabel.frame.origin.x, self.dishNameLabel.frame.origin.y, width, self.dishNameLabel.frame.size.height);
self.dishNameScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( width, self.dishNameScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Of course, you will have to replace your text and font with your respective specs